# Stack Smashing in GCC vs Clang (Possibly due to canaries)

Tags: c++, gcc, clang

I am trying to understand possible sources for `"stack smashing"` errors in GCC, but not Clang.

Specifically, when I compile a piece of code with just debug symbols

```
set(CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS_DEBUG "-g")
```

and use the GCC C++ compiler (GNU 5.4.0), the application crashes with

```
*** stack smashing detected ***: ./testprogram terminated
Aborted (core dumped)
```

However, when I use Clang 3.8.0, the program completes without error.

My first thought was that perhaps the canaries of GCC are catching a buffer overrun that Clang isn't. So I added the additional debug flag

```
set(CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS_DEBUG "-g -fstack-protector-all")
```

But Clang still compiles a program that runs without errors. To me this suggests that the issue likely is not a buffer overrun (as you commonly see with stack smashing errors), but an allocation issue.

In any case, when I add in the ASAN flags:

```
set(CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS_DEBUG "-g -fsanitize=address")
```

Both compilers yield a program that crashes with an identical error. Specifically,

GCC 5.4.0:

```
==1143==ERROR: AddressSanitizer failed to allocate 0xdfff0001000 (15392894357504) bytes at address 2008fff7000 (errno: 12)
==1143==ReserveShadowMemoryRange failed while trying to map 0xdfff0001000 bytes. Perhaps you're using ulimit -v
Aborted (core dumped)
```

Clang 3.8.0:

```
==1387==ERROR: AddressSanitizer failed to allocate 0xdfff0001000 (15392894357504) bytes at address 2008fff7000 (errno: 12)
==1387==ReserveShadowMemoryRange failed while trying to map 0xdfff0001000 bytes. Perhaps you're using ulimit -v
Aborted (core dumped)
```

Can somebody give me some hints on the likely source of this error? I am having an awefully hard time tracing down the line where this is occurring, as it is in a very large code base.

---

### EDIT

The issue is unresolved, but is isolated to the following function:

```
void get_sparsity(Data & data) {
    T x[n_vars] = {};
    T g[n_constraints] = {}; 
    for (Index j = 0; j < n_vars; j++) {

        const T x_j = x[j];
        x[j] = NAN;
        eval_g(n_vars, x, TRUE, n_constraints, g, &data);
        x[j] = x_j;

        std::vector<Index> nonzero_entries;
        for (Index i = 0; i < n_constraints; i++) {
            if (isnan(g[i])) {
                data.flattened_nonzero_rows.push_back(i);
                data.flattened_nonzero_cols.push_back(j);
                nonzero_entries.push_back(i);
            }
        }
        data.nonzeros.push_back(nonzero_entries);
    }
    int internal_debug_point = 5;
}
```

which is called like this:

```
get_sparsity(data);
int external_debug_point= 6;
```

However, when I put a debug point on the last line of the `get_sparsity` function, `internal_debug_point = 5`, it reaches that line without issue. However, when exiting the function, and before it hits the external debug point `external_debug_point = 6`, it crashes with the error

```
received signal SIGABRT, Aborted.
0x00007ffffe315428 in __GI_raise (sig=sig@entry=6) at ../sysdeps/unix/sysv/linux/raise.c:54
```

My guess is that GCC is only checking the canaries when exiting that function, and hence the error is actually occurring inside the function. Does that sound reasonable? If so, then is there a way to get GCC or clang to do more frequent canary checks?

Comment: That number of bytes doesn't look suspicious to you? Looks like you have used an address as a size. Can you provide simplified code that shows the problem? Without that we're all just guessing...

Comment: I have no idea where the error is occurring. So it is hard to track down.

Comment: The size seem suspicious, but in fact we are dealing with very very large matrices in the code.

Comment: What seems puzzling to me is why clang would not yield an error without ASAN, but GCC does

Comment: Why are you trying to allocate `15,392,894,357,504` bytes? (Unless you expect "very large matrices" to be 15Tb.) When you run the asan version under gdb, _what_ is requesting that allocation?

Comment: @bremen_matt Have you actually done the maths to see just how big that is?

Comment: Yes. I understand that we are talking > 1TB. But it is not clear to me where in the code is trying to allocate that memory

Comment: Actually, how can you be having a hard time tracing down where that is occurring, if it dumped a core file at exactly the point the sanitizer choked? What does the stack trace look like?

Comment: I understand that the problem is likely at a spot trying to allocate a ton of stack memory and crashing. It is just not clear to me where that is occurring.

Comment: You have a core file. Use it.

Comment: Ok. I will look at that next and report back

Comment: If the size you expect to allocate is 4096, I would suspect that you have either corrupted the variable that stores the size or used a bad type cast somewhere.

Comment: Hmm. Now trying to figure out why GCC isn't dumping a core, despite `core file size          (blocks, -c) 64`

Comment: Ah. I was running this in WSL. It seems that core dumps are not available: https://github.com/Microsoft/WSL/issues/1262

Comment: To the debugger I go...

Comment: I provided a bit more detail in case that suggests an idea for anybody.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Trying to figure out the source of the stack problems was getting nowhere. So I tried a different approach. Through debugging, I narrowed down the above function `get_sparsity` as the culprit. The debugger wasn't giving me any hints exactly WHERE the problem was occurring, but it was somewhere inside that function. With that information, I switched the only two stack variables in that function `x` and `g` to heap variables so that valgrind could help me find the error (sgcheck was coming up empty). Specifically, I modified the above code to

```
void get_sparsity(Data & data) {

    std::vector<T> x(n_vars, 0);
    std::vector<T> g(n_constraints, 0);

    /* However, for our purposes, it is easier to make an std::vector of Eigen
     * vectors, where the ith entry of "nonzero_entries" contains a vector of
     * indices in g for which g(indices) are nonzero when perturbing x(i).
     * If that sounds complicated, just look at the code and compare to
     * the code where we use the sparsity structure.
     */
    for (Index j = 0; j < n_vars; j++) {

        const T x_j = x[j];
        x[j] = NAN;
        Bool val = eval_g(n_vars, x.data(), TRUE, n_constraints, g.data(), &data);
        x[j] = x_j;

        std::vector<Index> nonzero_entries;
        for (Index i = 0; i < n_constraints; i++) {
            if (isnan(g[i])) {
                data.flattened_nonzero_rows.push_back(i);
                data.flattened_nonzero_cols.push_back(j);
                nonzero_entries.push_back(i);
            }
        }
        data.nonzeros.push_back(nonzero_entries);
    }
    int bob = 5;
    return;
}
```

and then `valgrind`ed it to find the offending line. Now that I know where the problem is occurring, I can fix the problem.

Comment: You could also have set a hardware watchpoint on the location of the stack canary using GDB. But moving the arrays to the heap is a good approach, too.

Answer (score 1):

I suspect ASan is running out of memory.

I don't think the ASan errors mean your program is trying to allocate that memory, it means ASan is trying to allocate it for itself (it says "shadow memory" which is what ASan uses to keep track of the memory your program allocates).

If the number of iterations (and size of array) `n_vars` is large, then the function will use extra memory for a new `std::vector` in every loop, forcing ASan to track more and more memory.

You could try moving the local vector out of the loop (which will likely increase the performance of the function anyway):

```
std::vector<Index> nonzero_entries;
for (Index j = 0; j < n_vars; j++) {

    // ...

    for (Index i = 0; i < n_constraints; i++) {
        if (isnan(g[i])) {
            data.flattened_nonzero_rows.push_back(i);
            data.flattened_nonzero_cols.push_back(j);
            nonzero_entries.push_back(i);
        }
    }
    data.nonzeros.push_back(nonzero_entries);
    nonzero_entries.clear();
}
```

This will reuse the same memory for `nonzero_entries` instead of allocating and deallcoating memory for a new vector every iteration.